# как написать свою реализацию serialization api

Tags: java

нужно сериализовать класс в виде массива байтов без "built-in serialization api" т.е. , как я понял, не использовать обертки библиотечных потоков ввода вывода, а написать свою.  Не могу понять куда копать и какой примерный алгоритм действий при данной реализации? вот моя реализация

```
 public static byte[] documentToByte(Document document) throws TransformerException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(bos);
    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
    transformer.transform(source, result);
    byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();

    return data;
}
```

Comment: Судя по задаче, вам не поток нужен, а сериализатор. Сериализуйте в поток, а в качестве потока используйте экземпляр [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html).

Comment: @Devoli, комментарии плохо подходят для кода, перенесите его в ваш вопрос (кнопка `править`)

Comment: @Devoli В этом коде serialization api это `Transformer`. Кажется, хотят, чтобы вы написали свой `Transformer`.

Comment: Сначала надо десериализовать а потом менять сериализатор.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko можете подсказать как бы вы это реализовывали?

Comment: @RomanC что вы под этим подразумеваете?

Comment: Чтобы писать свой сериализатор нужно иметь основу, вот я и предлагаю сначала десерелизовать в java а потом уже доделывать сериализатор, надеюсь понятно о чем идёт речь. Просто кидаться тут вопросами типа написать свою апи, покажи...